# Django: How to list or loop multiple classes .as_view() with very similar methods. (How to simplify mutiple classes that are very similar)

Tags: python, django, class, django-views

I have the following classes in views.py

```
class Base():
   def function:
      ***blah blah blah***
      return data # a list of data [data1, data2, data3, ...]

class JSONView1(Base,JSONBase)
   def get_data(self):
      json_data1 = list(Base().function()[0])
      return json_data1
   
class JSONView2(Base,JSONBase):
    def get_data(self):
        json_data2 = list(Base().function()[1])
        return json_data2

JSONView1 = JSONView1.as_view()
JSONView2 = JSONView2.as_view()
```

Mainly, in class **Base** I build a data list, then I create 2 classes, each one calling a specific data from class Base, e.g., **JSONView1** calls data1 and **JSONView2** calls data2. These JSON classes are important because they convert the data to a JSON script using JSONBase (no shown here for simplicity).
Finally I use .as_view() in views.py because I will call them in urls.py.

The problem is that this is ok for 2 Views, but what if I have +5. I don't want to create a class for each new data in the list because the only difference between the classes is just the index, 0,1,2,3,.... the rest is the same

I would like to have something like

```
for k in range(5):
   class JSONView[k](Base,JSONClass)
   def get_data(self):
      json_data[k] = list(Base().function()[k])
      return json_data[k]
   JSONView[k] = JSONView[k].as_view()
```

Iterate over the code itself changing the index. I'm not an expert so an example to solve this would be thoroughly appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an arg `k` to `__init__` method and then use it in `get_data` method.

It will look kind of this:

```
class JSONView(...):
    def __init__(self, k, *args, **kwargs):
        self.k = k
        super(JSONView, self).__init__(*args, kwargs)

    def get_data(self):
        json_data = list(Base().function()[self.k])
        return json_data
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I can iterate JSONView(k) but it gives me the object and .as_view() doesn't accept the object. e.g., JSONView(0).as_view() gives an error. How can I solve this

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes with superclasses and an d give an attributedict (a key, attribute, and value, function or literal value.

See this example here:

https://python-course.eu/oop/dynamically-creating-classes-with-type.php

Because this is what you're asking to do, sorry I dont have time to apply it to your code, if you need more clarity than the link provides, send a message and I'll update this answer to give code examples as you've provided

Comment: I was able to do what you said however iteraton with a key value gives me an object, and it is not accepted with .as_view(). e.g., JSONView(0).as_view() shows error, while JSONView.as_view() is ok. How can I solve this?

Comment: The reason is because I didn't use type as suggested. I still cannot figure out how to properly use type() to get a class and not an object

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news here but all things classy are generally objects. As for your question, why can't you just call `self.function()` and furthermore, if you want to be clever with you class based view then take a look at super() as this is how we get the values of the functions we subclass from, and then customise.